# Double http request when IE document mode is 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am using `rails 3.2.15` and `ruby 1.9.3`. In my application When I use `Internet Explorer document mode = 8`, it produce a single http request.

> Ex : Started GET "/appointments/new?r=874" for XXXXXXX at 2013-12-31
>   10:28:13 +0000 Processing by AppointmentsController#new as JS

If I change the `document mode as 9` then it produce two HTTP requests.

> EX : Started GET "/appointments/new?r=156" for XXXXXXX at 2013-12-31 10:27:19 +0000
>   Started GET "/appointments/new" for XXXXXXX at
>   2013-12-31 10:27:19 +0000
>   Processing by AppointmentsController#new as
>   JS   Parameters: {"r"=>"156"}
>    Processing by AppointmentsController#new
>   as HTML

I don't know why this happens. Please suggest the route cast of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my issue and the culprit is "`prototype.js`". I downloaded the latest version of 'prototype.js' file (from http://prototypejs.org/download/) and tested in `IE 9, 10 and 11`. It's working as charm.